# How to give a different view for each user in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

So I have my table `users` and each record has a `username` field

and I have my root to controller `main` and action `index

```
root :to => 'pages#main'
```

so if go to `http://mydomain.com` It'll show my `main#index` page and i have the `about` and `contact` pages as well.

but if i go to `http://mydomain.com/Mr_Nizzle` it shows me the page of the user `Mr_Nizzle` which is on `users#show` (just like example) and as well for the other users to show every user's page...

is it right if i go =>

```
match ':username' => 'users#show'

match 'contact_us' => 'main#contact'

match 'about' => 'main#about'

root :to => 'pages#main'
```

so i can leave all the logic on route instead of in the main controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your asking, however [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) may be of some help. I think (at least for about and contact) the correct syntax is `match '/contact_us' => 'main#contact` (the same for about but replace contact with about), the `root :to => 'pages#main'` is correct (that's the same as doing match '/' => 'pages#main')

What are you asking about the `match ':username' => 'users#show'`? Do you want (for example) a url to be http://mydomain.com/users_username ? Where users_username is the name of the user's profile that they are navigating to? If so, i think you can do something like `match '/:username' => 'users#show'` but i'm not entirely sure.

Get back to me on what works and what doesn't

Comment: Well yes the thing with `users_username` was exactly wy i was trying to do just had to turn my routes upside down for the priority of `about` and `contact_us` otherwise it'll be taking them as `:username`